# How to assign gridview column width automatically according to its value in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I have one GridView which has multiple columns. Here I just mentioned only the two columns in the GridView.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tot. Qty." ItemStyle-Width="30px" ControlStyle-Width="30px" >
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblTotQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalQuantity") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle Width="30px" />
<ControlStyle Width="30px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="UoM" HeaderText="UoM" ItemStyle-Width="25px" />
```

But the problem here is, when the Total Quantity column values is greater than 6 digits. then the value is displays continuously along with the next column value "UoM".
How to increase the GridView column width of "Total Quantity" according to the Column's value?

Comment: If you want them to set them manually, not alter them in code, and change size equally together in the browser, then you will have to use JavaScript.

Comment: What reason to use Label control inside ItemTemplate? Why you can't remove ControlStyle-Width property and use plain `<%# Eval("TotalQuantity") %>` expression instead of label control? Do you need to get that label in code-behind on RowDataBound event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just NOT specify a width at all and let is size dynamically?

Alternative: calculate the width in code behind and set it there.

Comment: apart from that you are using an asp:Label where in my opinion you should be using an asp:Literal because a label is supposed to be associated to another control.